# SQL query with multiple joins (And Exists?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a sql query where i am getting data from tables User,UserDetails and UserData.
i also have to check the table ConditionCheck, for any entries for this particular user. This table can have multiple condition checks for each user.
if table ConditionCheck contains even one entry of 2 or 3, i dont return any user data.

I wrote the query as follows:

```
select A.Column1, A.Column2, B.Column1, isnull(D.Column1, '')
from User A  WITH (NOLOCK) 
inner join UserDetails B  WITH (NOLOCK) on(B.id = A.id)
left join UserData C  WITH (NOLOCK) on (C.uid = B.uid)
left join ConditionCheck CC  WITH (NOLOCK)  on(CC.S_id = B.S_id)
left outer join MoreData D  WITH (NOLOCK)  on (D.id = A.id)
where A.Column1 = 'ABC' and CC.T_id not in(2, 3)
```

if a user has rows with entries 1,2,4,5 in CC, i dont want to return the user details because of condition 2 existing. but this query returns user details if the user has rows other than  2 or 3 existing.

Comment: Any specific reason you use both `left join` and `left outer join` in your query? Not that it matters, I am just curious (if you think they will perform differently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to add a `NOT EXISTS` clause to your query, and remove the `LEFT JOIN` to your ConditionalCheck table, since you're not actually doing anything with the data there:

```
Select      A.Column1, A.Column2, B.Column1, IsNull(D.Column1, '')
From        User            A  With (NoLock) 
Inner Join  UserDetails     B  With (NoLock)    On  (B.id = A.id)
Left Join   UserData        C  With (NoLock)    On  (C.uid = B.uid)
Left Join   MoreData        D  With (NoLock)    On  (D.id = A.id)
Where       A.Column1 = 'ABC' 
And Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    ConditionalCheck    CC
    Where   CC.S_id = B.S_id
    And     CC.T_id In (2,3)
)
```

As a side note, for the context of the query provided, the `LEFT JOIN` to the *UserData* table is also unnecessary.

Comment: I tried this. but it is not working. i had a user with 2 rows in CC with conditions 1 and 3. but the user details are still being returned with this version of query. it is working similar to my earlier query.

Comment: I got it to work. you are right. the table C is not required in the join. only A,B and D should in the join. then I put C and CC tables in the NOT EXISTS clause. it started working.

Answer (score 2):

As you speculated in your title, it's probably better to do this with `EXISTS` than to have a proper join to the `ConditionCheck` table. Even if your `WHERE` clause were doing what you want, you'd still have the problem that a user with multiple records in the `ConditionCheck` table would appear multiple times in your result set. Try something like this:

```
select 
    A.Column1, 
    A.Column2, 
    B.Column1, 
    isnull(D.Column1, '')
from
    User A  WITH (NOLOCK) 
    inner join UserDetails B  WITH (NOLOCK) on(B.id = A.id)
    left join UserData C  WITH (NOLOCK) on (C.uid = B.uid)
    left outer join MoreData D  WITH (NOLOCK)  on (D.id = A.id)
where
    A.Column1 = 'ABC' and 
    not exists
    (
        select 1 
        from
            ConditionCheck CC with (nolock) 
        where
            CC.S_id = B.S_id and 
            CC.T_id in (2, 3)
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a left join and you're not using it you could use and anti-join here by changing your join to include `IN(2,3)` and adding a null check on cc.

```
SELECT A.column1, 
       A.column2, 
       B.column1, 
       Isnull(D.column1, '') 
FROM   USER A WITH (nolock) 
       INNER JOIN userdetails B WITH (nolock) 
               ON( B.id = A.id ) 
       LEFT JOIN userdata C WITH (nolock) 
              ON ( C.uid = B.uid ) 
       LEFT JOIN conditioncheck CC WITH (nolock) 
              ON( CC.s_id = B.s_id 
                  AND CC.t_id IN( 2, 3 ) ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN moredata D WITH (nolock) 
                    ON ( D.id = A.id ) 
WHERE  A.column1 = 'ABC' 
       AND cc.s_id IS NULL
```

You could also use `not exists` (other answers) `not in` , `<> ALL` and `EXCEPT`

Also those NoLock join hints allow inconsistant data to be returned. Are you sure you want to do that?